# how to prevent spread operator from maintaining original reference?

Tags: javascript

I'm setting an array to a property like this:

originalFacilityList: [...maintenanceInfo.Facilities]

However, when I check originalFacilityList downstream, it reflects the updates that were made to the maintenanceInfo.Facilities array.  I was thinking that the spread operator was used to break that reference.  Am I doing something incorrectly in this example?

Comment: For a deep copy, you can try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(maintenanceInfo.Facilities))`

Comment: Does it reflect updates that were made to that array? Or does it reflect updates that were made to **objects inside** that array?

Comment: @Quentin - specifically it reflects updates that were made to objects inside that array.  for example, if I updated the City of the second Facility from Austin to Dallas, Dallas would be reflected on the facility object of the array that I spread out before the edit facility was updated

Comment: @iron.man.rball — then that's the issue. The spread operator gives you a new array, but it has the same objects in it. It is only a shallow copy.

Comment: spread operator only makes a shallow copy, not a deep one. @Unmitigated has given one way to do an arbitrary deep copy, but if those objects don't have nested objects or arrays you could also do `originalFacilityList = maintenanceInfo.Facilities.map(obj => ({...obj}))`

Comment: I generally use https://github.com/immerjs/immer for this sort of problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

When you do this `originalFacilityList: [...maintenanceInfo.Facilities]` you are effectively cloning the array. More precisely, you are doing a **shallow clone**, as opposed to **deep clone**.

As a result, when you add or remove items from the new array, the changes do not reflect on the original array:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3];

const shallowClone = [...arr];

shallowClone.push(4);

console.log(shallowClone, arr);
```

What you have probably noticed is that the objects contained in the array are actually referenced by the old and the new array:

```js
const arr = [{ property: 'value' }];

const shallowClone = [...arr];

arr[0].newProperty = 'newValue';

console.log(shallowClone);
```

If you want to avoid that, then you need to **deep clone** the array. There is no native solution for this, except some solutions like `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(` that are very hacky and only work with serializable objects (does not preserve functions, prototypal inheritance, etc...), so either implement it yourself, or use utility libraries like [Lodash's `cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep).