Javascript, clone array but when function called the original array is altered as well
I have created a very simple example to show the problem I am facing when using creating an array object in Javascript.
I want to clone the array and call a function, inside that function I want to be able to change a team name to another and return it, when I do this the original value is also changed.
I have made this super simplistic to illustrate the problem.


a = [];
a[0]    = {};
a[0].team = "Arsenal";
    
a[1]    = {};
a[1].team = "Chelsea";

a[2]    = {};
a[2].team = "West Ham";

function change_team(d, club){
    d[1].team = club;
    return d;
};

b = [...a]; // Clone a[];
change_team(b, "spurs");

// Should read Arsenal, Chelsea, West Ham;
for(n=0; n<a.length; n++){
    console.log(n+"] "+a[n].team);
};

// Should read Arsenal, Spurs, West Ham;
for(n=0; n<a.length; n++){
    console.log(n+"] "+b[n].team);
};




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68718571/how-to-prevent-spread-operator-from-maintaining-original-reference

The spread only does a shallow clone.

build a JSON and parse it. voilà.

Brilliant - Thanks.

or use structuredClone?
